# How to load a list from a list inside an object in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, dictionary

I have a list of objects, and inside these objects I have another list. I would like to know if there's a simple way to load a list of those lists inside the object. I want to choose a parameter from the object (userCode for example), and I want that list to return all the lists from all the objects with the matching userCode.

If anyone could help me, I'll be forever grateful.

Thank you

Comment: Post your current code.

Comment: list.get(i).get(i).getAttribute()

Answer (score 0):

Well the most straight forward way of iterating should be fine here. Just loop through the list and get the lists from the objects and add them to another list. below is a sample template.

```
List<List<T>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();
for (Obj o : listOfObjects){
    listOfLists.add(o.list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let assume you have populated a list of lists somewhere like this:

```
List<List<Object>> list1 = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();

    for(List<Object> list : list1){
        List<Object> list2 = new ArrayList<Object>();
        list.add(list2);
    }
```

Then you could create something like this to find your object:

```
List<List<Object>> find = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
    for(List<Object> list : list1){
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            if(list.get(i).toString().equals("userCode")){
                find.add(list);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return find;
```

Note that I assumed an Object you should put your condition in the if statment.

Answer (score 0):

Start with some object that has a userCode and list fields:

```
 class X {
    private int userCode;
    private List<Y> list;
    int getUserCode(){ return userCode; }
    List<Y> getList() { return list; }
 }
```

and assume we've got a list of these guys:

```
 List<X> listOfX;
```

What you want is covert each `X` in the list to an entry in a map. Here's a simple function that converts of list of X's to a Map

```
 Map<Integer, List<Y>> buildMap(List<X> list) {
      Map<Integer, List<Y>> map = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Y>>();
      for(X x:list) {
          map.put(x.getUserCode(), x.getList());
      }
      return map;
}
```

The keys in the map are the userCode's from your list of X's and the values are X's list fields:

```
 List<Y> listOfY = map.get(someUserCode);
```